# unite several dataframe columns into one in presence of empty or NaN in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with columns A, B and C. I want to unite the columns (like unite in tidyverse in r) into one column D, with text separated with comma. All columns contains some empty values.

I did the following:

```
import pandas as pd
dfm = pd.DataFrame({ 'A': ['apple', '', ''],
                    'B': ['', 'orange', 'grape'],
                     'C': ['pear', 'apple', '']})
dfm['D'] = dfm[['A', 'B', 'C']].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x) if x!='', axis=1)
dfm
```

I got the error like below:

```
dfm['D'] = dfm[['A', 'B', 'C']].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x) if x!='', axis=1)
                                                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Does anyone know what I did wrong? It seems that if I remove `if x!=''`, I can united the columns. But because there are some empty entries, I got some commas next to each other, which is not I want.

Does anyone know what I did wrong and how I can fix that? Thanks.

Comment: What is your expected result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
dfm['D'] = dfm[['A', 'B', 'C']].apply(lambda x: ','.join(a for a in x if a), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
       A       B      C             D
0  apple           pear    apple,pear
1         orange  apple  orange,apple
2          grape                grape
```

Comment: Perhaps `a for a in x if a`

Comment: @Alexander That's a great idea. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I will do

```
dfm.mask(dfm=='').stack().groupby(level=0).apply(','.join)
0      apple,pear
1    orange,apple
2           grape
dtype: object
```